# Inserting id that is varchar into uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, guid, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to insert data from one table to another. The source table contains a GUID that is a text field right now. I want to insert it into a Uniqueidentifier field. This is the query and the error.

```
insert into Tag 
(
    BusinessId, 
    AdImage, 
    AdSize, 
    DayCycleId, 
    CreatedOn, 
    IsActive, 
    Name, 
    CreatedBy
)
select cast(ID as uniqueidentifier), 
    [IMAGE], 
    '1', 
    cast('71479D27-D7A2-4439-99CB-0B536DCEFB45' as uniqueidentifier), 
    GETDATE(), 
    1, 
    'NA', 
    cast('49493D4F-A0B0-43A5-8B32-45572E4D7E43' as uniqueidentifier) 
from IMPORT
```

Error:

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: SQL Server? Which version? What format does `IMPORT.ID` have *exactly*?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. IMPORT.ID is nvarchar(32).

Comment: You're aware that a GUID needs 36 characters, not just 32, because of the dashes? I suppose that your GUIDs got truncated and therefore cannot be converted back to valid GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Alter you type of property ID  to `nvarchar(36)`

nvarchar(32) or < 36 not work